# Transforming string data in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, string, naming-conventions

I need to convert some data stored as *varchar* in a SQL Server database that I want to change from **CamelCase** to **delimiter-separated**. I know how to do this trivially in C# but not T-SQL. Any ideas?

Comment: Not an answer, so I won't post it as an answer; But why not do it using the tool you know best? (I recognize there may be some extremely good reasons, which is why I'm asking 'why', as opposed to telling you not to do it that way.. hehe).

Comment: It's more efficient to do it in the database and I can't install C# objects into this database for security reasons. (it's a publicly facing Federal sql server)

Comment: See, told you there may be some extremely good reasons!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Alter FUNCTION dbo.GetDelimitedString 
(   
    @CamelCaseString nvarchar(max) 
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result_String nvarchar(max)
    Select @Result_String = @CamelCaseString

    DECLARE @pos INT
    DECLARE @DelimiterCount INT
    Select @Pos = 2
    Select @DelimiterCount = 0        

    WHILE @pos <= DATALENGTH(@CamelCaseString)
    BEGIN
        IF ASCII(SUBSTRING(@CamelCaseString, @pos, 1)) BETWEEN 65 AND 90

        BEGIN
            set @Result_String = STUFF(@Result_String,@Pos + @DelimiterCount,0,',')
            Set @DelimiterCount = @DelimiterCount + 1
        END
    SET @pos = @pos + 1;
    END

    RETURN @RESULT_STRING
END
```

And you can use this function -

```
select dbo.GetDelimitedString('TestStringInCamelCase')
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't SQL Server on hand to try, but you need a loop testing for:

`CODE(SUBSTRING (xx, thatpositions, 1)) BETWEEN 64 and 89`

Then insert your delimiter:

```
SUBSTRING (xx, 1, thatpositions -1) + delimiter + SUBSTRING (xx, thatpositions, 8000)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have C# code to do this, and are using SQL Server 2005+, you can expose the .NET code as a TSQL function (or stored procedure) via SQLCLR.  Check that you're allowed -- most don't, for sake of support and/or great potential for misuse.  Also be aware that SQL Server 2005 uses .NET 2.0 while SQL Server 2008 (incl. R2) is .NET v3.5.

[This article](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/04/18/2917.aspx) caters to enabling SQLCLR (doesn't require a restart), building, deploying & using a SQLCLR for regex support.

It's my preference to use TSQL whenever possible though.

Comment: I can't install C# objects into this database for security reasons or I would have.

Comment: @craigmoliver: Understood - very common approach in most shops.  I'll leave this up for those who might want to.  I voted for gbn already anyhow